# How to check new opportunity owner has access to the record

Tags: apex, before-trigger

i am trying to update opportunity owner from custom owner field to standardrd owner field before performing this operation i want to check if owner has access to the record  how can i check in apex

```
public with sharing class UpdateOwner {
    public static void UpdateOppty(List < Opportunity > listOpportunity, Map < Id, Opportunity > oldMap) {
        for (Opportunity Opp: listOpportunity) {
            if (opp.Owner__c != null && opp.Owner__c != oldMap.get(Opp.id).Owner__c) {
                if (Schema.sObjectType.Opportunity.fields.OwnerId.isUpdateable()) {
                    id usrid = opp.Owner__c;

                    List < Opportunity > Oppty = new List < Opportunity > ([SELECT Id, Name, Opportunity_Owner__c, UserRecordAccess.HasReadAccess, UserRecordAccess.HasTransferAccess, UserRecordAccess.MaxAccessLevel
                        FROM Opportunity
                    ]);
                    if (Oppty.Owner__c.MaxAccessLevel == true) {
                        Opp.OwnerId = opp.Owner__c;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check the record access using  [UserRecordAccess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm)

Doing the SOQL on UserRecordAccess Object you can check the `HasEditAccess,HasDeleteAccess,HasReadAccess` access, So you will check in your code to add a condition with appropriate access you want to check. with userId(owner in your case) and recordid.

```
SELECT RecordId, HasEditAccess,HasDeleteAccess,HasReadAccess FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId = :userid AND RecordId = :recId
```

Comment: make sure you are using valid ownerId(userid) , please run the above SOQL in anonymous window to test.